# Common print function for all variants of maps C++ STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am brushing up some skills on C++ STL and I wrote a basic insertion/deletion code for maps.

Below is the code.
It is taking some inputs from user and inserting/deleting accordingly.
Very simple code.

But the issue is I have to write separate print functions for every map variant.
Is there anything I can do to make it common as we do in templates?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

void print(const map<int, string>& mp)
{
    cout << "Contents of map: { ";

    for(auto& it: mp)
    {
        cout << it.first << " -> "  << it.second << " ";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}

void print(const multimap<int, string>& mp)
{
    cout << "Contents of multi map: { ";

    for(auto& it: mp)
    {
        cout << it.first << " -> "  << it.second << " ";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}

void print(const unordered_map<int, string>& mp)
{
    cout << "Contents of unordered map: { ";

    for(auto& it: mp)
    {
        cout << it.first << " -> "  << it.second << " ";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}

void print(const unordered_multimap<int, string>& mp)
{
    cout << "Contents of unordered multi map: { ";

    for(auto& it: mp)
    {
        cout << it.first << " -> "  << it.second << " ";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    map<int, string> mp1;
    multimap<int, string> mp2;
    unordered_map<int, string> mp3;
    unordered_multimap<int, string> mp4;

    int value = 0;
    string str;

    cout << "Inserting..." << endl;

    while(value >= 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> value;

        if(value >= 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter string: ";
            cin >> str;

            mp1.insert(pair<int, string>(value, str));
            mp2.insert(pair<int, string>(value, str));
            mp3.insert(pair<int, string>(value, str));
            mp4.insert(pair<int, string>(value, str));
        }
    }

    print(mp1);
    print(mp2);
    print(mp3);
    print(mp4);

    value = 0;

    cout << "Removing..." << endl;

    while(value >= 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter number: ";
        cin >> value;

        if(value >= 0)
        {
            // removing by value
            mp1.erase(value);
            mp2.erase(value);
            mp3.erase(value);
            mp4.erase(value);
        }
    }

    print(mp1);
    print(mp2);
    print(mp3);
    print(mp4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll love this Q-> https://stackoverflow.com/q/4850473/451600. Plenty of suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, that is, indeed, what templates are used for, right?

```
template<typename T>
void print(const T& mp)
{
    cout << "Contents of map: { ";

    for(auto& it: mp)
    {
        cout << it.first << " -> "  << it.second << " ";
    }

    cout << "}" << endl;
}
```

This'll work as long as only maps, or reasonable facsimiles thereof, are passed to `print()` (and both keys and values in the maps have a working `<<` overload). Otherwise, it might become necessary to use SFINAE or C++20 concepts to constrain overload resolution.